# Same query working in MySQL, and not in Java Client

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

This query retrieves the correct value when run in MySQL workbench.

```
select person_id from person where person_name='John Adam';
```

But when I run it from by Java code, it gives the exception at the line in which executeQuery() is called.

```
SQLState: 42S22
Error Code: 1054
Message: Unknown column 'John Adam' in 'where clause'
```

My code is:

```
String inputname= JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( "Enter person's name:" ); 
String query= "select person_id from person where person_name= "+ inputname;

try {
    stmt=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query); // EXCEPTION AT THIS LINE
    while (rs.next()){
    rid= rs.getInt("person_id");
    } // .....
```

**What do you think can be the reason for this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with single quotes

```
String query= "select person_id" + 
               "from person where person_name= '"+ inputname+"'";
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put quotes around your input

```
String query= "select person_id from person " + 
              "where person_name= '"+ inputname + "'";
```

Or better use [*Prepared Statements*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to let the escaping do the program for you automatically.